# Does $D_4$ have a verbal subgroup of order 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups, verbal-subgroups

Does $D_4$ have a verbal subgroup of order 4?

How did this question arise:

In the comments $Q_8$ ad $D_4$ were pointed to be a possible counterexample to this question: [Is it true, that for any two non-isomorphic finite groups $G$ and $H$ there exists such a group word $w$, that $|V_w(G)| \neq |V_w(H)|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111327/is-it-true-that-for-any-two-non-isomorphic-finite-groups-g-and-h-there-exis)

However, $Q_8$ does not have a characteristic subgroup of order $4$, whereas $D_4$ has $3$ normal subgroups of order $4$. So, if one of those subgroups happens to be verbal for some group word $w$, then $Q_8$ ad $D_4$ are definitely not a counterexample.

If such $w$ exists, then it is clearly not an identity in $D_4$. Also, $w \neq [x, y]$,  as $D_4’ \cong C_2$, $w \neq x$,  as $V_{x^3}(D_4) \cong D_4$, $w \neq x^2$  as $V_{x^2}(D_4) \cong C_2$ and $w \neq x^3$,  as $V_{x^3}(D_4) \cong D_4$.

However, I do not know, how to proceed further.

Comment: Is $Q_8$ the quaternion group of order $8$? That has a few normal subgroups of order $4$.

Comment: @MattSamuel, that was a typo. I meant "characteristic subgroups", when I talked about $Q_8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is apparently no:  none of the three subgroups of $D_4$ of order $4$ are [verbal](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Verbal_subgroup#Examples_of_subgroups_not_satisfying_the_property).

Incidentally,  any subgroup of order four in $Q_8$ is normal (since of index $2$).